# How to parse json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to parse following json object

```
{ "info": [ { "systemIp": "192.168.1.1", "status": "done 956" }, { "systemIp": "192.153.1.1", "status": "done" } ] }
```

In Javascript or jQuery can anybody help?

Output should be like

```
systemIp 192.168.1.1

status done

systemIp 192.153.1.1

status done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
    var abc =  { "info": [ { "systemIp": "192.168.1.1", "status": "done 956" }, { "systemIp": "192.153.1.1", "status": "done" } ] };

            $.each(abc.info,function(i,val){
                alert("systemIp : "+val.systemIp);
                alert("status : " +val.status);
            });

            /*  other way ot iterate */

           $.each(abc.info,function(i,outer){
                $.each(outer,function(j,inner){
                  alert(j+" : "+inner);
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not very efficient way, but this will serve your purpose

```
var a ={ "info": [ { "systemIp": "192.168.1.1", "status": "done 956" }, 
         { "systemIp": "192.153.1.1", "status": "done" } ] }

    var objL = a['info']
    for(var i = 0;i<objL.length;i++){
      for(keys in objL[i]){
        console.log( keys + ' ' +objL[i][keys])  
      }
    }
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/w9oejsta/2/)

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript: [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

With jQuery: [`jQuery.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Comment: using for loop how to iterate values

Comment: @srihari with jQuery, you can use [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

With JavaScript:

    json.info.forEach(function(value, index) {
        console.log(value);
    })

Comment: $.each(result.info, function(v,k){
v // value 
k // k is stand for key or index



})

Comment: @srihari: It seems you would gain the most from reading a tutorial about JavaScript basics: http://eloquentjavascript.net/02_program_structure.html#h_oupMC+5FKN, http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html . This is pretty fundamental stuff.